# Relacionamento da anotaçoes Hibernate (Error)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-jpa, persistência

###### Estou com error na parte de anotaçoes do hibernate.

Ola pessoal !

- UML do problema exemplo [UML exemplo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJjoQ.png)
- Error do console:

  ```
  Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: io.helioanacronista.DesafioORM.entities.Bloco.atividade
  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
  ```

---

#### Classe Bloco

- A classes que acredito que está dando error

```java
package io.helioanacronista.DesafioORM.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.Instant;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_bloco")
public class Bloco {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE")
    private Instant inicio;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE")
    private Instant fim;

    //Relacionamento de classe ->

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "blocos")
    private Atividade atividade;


}
```

#### Classe Atividade

```java
package io.helioanacronista.DesafioORM.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_atividade")
public class Atividade {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String nome;

    private String descricao;

    private Double preco;


    //Relacionamento de classe ->

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.categoria")
    private Set<Categoria> categorias = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "bloco_id")
    private Bloco blocos;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "participantes_atividades",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "atividade_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "participate_id")
    )
    private Set<Participante> participantes = new HashSet<>();


}
```

---

###### Estou com dificuldade identificar qual parte do error pelo console como ele diz aqui

```
io.helioanacronista.DesafioORM.entities.Bloco.atividade
```

- Seria na classe Bloco no Método que chama o relacionamento de atividades? e a anotação estaria errada?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

### Fiz essas alterações e deu certo

- na classe atividade

Troquei anotação de @joinTable para @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "atividades")
e categoria com ManyToOne

```java
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="categoria_id")
    private Categoria categorias;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "atividades")
    private Set<Participante> participantes = new HashSet<>();
```

- na classe Bloco

```java
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ativiade_id")
    private Atividade atividade;
```

- A classe que precisava fazer o tratamento com notação @JoinTable era a participante

```java
@ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "tb_participante_atividade",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "participante_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "atividade_id"))
    private Set<Atividade> atividades = new HashSet<>();
```